# nullglob and arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, glob, shopt

I can create an array, then delete from this array

```
$ foo=(a b c)

$ unset foo[0]

$ echo ${foo[*]}
b c
```

However if `nullglob` is set then I cannot delete from the array

```
$ shopt -s nullglob

$ foo=(a b c)

$ unset foo[0]

$ echo ${foo[*]}
a b c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unset 'foo[0]'
```

> Bash thinks the `var[1]` is a glob, doesn't find a file that matches it, and 
>   per instruction of `nullglob` removes it, causing your script to run `unset`
>   instead of `unset var[1]` - and nothing gets unset. The correct way to fix this 
>   issue is to quote the variable name (and always specify `-v` explicitly):
>   `unset -v 'var[1]'`.

[§ nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob)

Comment: I spent two days and finally found that nullglob was the culprit! Thanks for the *correct* way to use `unset`

Comment: With a variable as the subscript, use double quotes, like this: `unset -v "var[$subscript]".