# Associative array not unset when nullglob is set

Tags: bash, associative-array, glob, quotes, shopt

When I set nullglob in bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

and then declare an associative array:

```
declare -A arr=( [x]=y )
```

I cannot unset specific keys within the array:

```
unset arr[x]
echo ${#arr[@]} # still 1
```

However, unsetting `nullglob` makes this operation work like I expect:

```
shopt -u nullglob
unset arr[x]
echo ${#arr[@]} # now it's 0; x has been removed
```

What's going on here? I don't see how shell globbing could be relevant to the situation. I've tested this on bash 4.4.19 and 5.0.0.

Comment: This is closely a duplicate of [nullglob and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15897473/5291015)

Comment: See `echo unset arr[x]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be explained by reference the the `bash` documentation (the `man` page), paraphrased here:

> After word splitting, unless the `-f` option has been set, Bash scans each word for the characters `'*'`, `'?'`, and `'['`. If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern.
>
> ***If no matching filenames are found, and the shell option `nullglob` is disabled, the word is left unchanged. If the `nullglob` option is set, and no matches are found, the word is removed.***

In other words, `nullglob` affects what will happen to your `arr[x]` argument. It will either be left alone or removed.

You can see this effect by turning on echo-before-execute flag with `set -x`:

```
pax$ declare -A arr=( [x]=y )
pax$ shopt -s nullglob
pax$ set -x
pax$ unset arr[x]
+ unset
```

Note that this is the "word is removed" case. The "word is left unchanged" case is show thus:

```
pax$ shopt -u nullglob
+ shopt -u nullglob
pax$ unset arr[x]
+ unset 'arr[x]'
```

That final echoed command above also provides a clue as to how to delete an entry if you have enable `nullglob`. Just quote the argument to prevent expansion:

```
unset 'arr[x]'
```

This will work regardless of the `nullglob` setting, because of the section regarding quoting in the documentation:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.

Comment: Thanks! I would not be able to write a bash script without SO. I would have spent hours trying to figure this out. Anyone got an opinion about whether `nullglob` should be on or off by default?

Comment: Just FTR, the array doesn't have to be associative for this weirdness to happen. Compare `shopt -u nullglob; a=(unset_me); unset a[0]; echo "${a[@]}"` versus `shopt -s nullglob; a=(unset_me); unset a[0]; echo "${a[@]}"`; exactly the same thing.